# How to deploy jBPM 3.2.2 console on Oracle 10g iAS

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, jbpm

Does anybody have experience regarding deployment of the jBPM Administration Console on Oracle 10g iAS?

I successfully deployed it using an .ear, security mappings working, I can even login to the console, Hibernate finds the JNDI datasource but it cannot find the TransactionManager. 
I see no log, only the exception thrown in the jsf page:

[image: The error, TransactionManager not found]

Can anybody help me?

The hibernate.cfg.xml file now looks like this:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <!-- hibernate dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection properties (begin) ===
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:jbpm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    ==== JDBC connection properties (end) -->

    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- DataSource properties (begin) -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/JbpmDS</property>
    <!-- DataSource properties (end) -->

    <!-- JTA transaction properties (begin) -->
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
   <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>-->
    <!-- JTA transaction properties (end) -->

    <!-- CMT transaction properties (begin) ===
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    ==== CMT transaction properties (end) -->

    <!-- logging properties (begin) -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <--==== logging properties (end) -->

    <!-- ############################################ -->
    <!-- # mapping files with external dependencies # -->
    <!-- ############################################ -->

    <!-- following mapping file has a dependendy on   -->
    <!-- 'bsh-{version}.jar'.                         -->
    <!-- uncomment this if you don't have bsh on your -->
    <!-- classpath.  you won't be able to use the     -->
    <!-- script element in process definition files   -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/action/Script.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- following mapping files have a dependendy on  -->
    <!-- 'jbpm-identity.jar', mapping files            -->
    <!-- of the pluggable jbpm identity component.     -->
    <!-- Uncomment the following 3 lines if you        -->
    <!-- want to use the jBPM identity mgmgt           -->
    <!-- component.                                    -->
    <!-- identity mappings (begin) -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/Group.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/Membership.hbm.xml"/>
    <!-- identity mappings (end) -->

    <!-- following mapping files have a dependendy on  -->
    <!-- the JCR API                                   -->
    <!-- jcr mappings (begin) ===
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/JcrNodeInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    ==== jcr mappings (end) -->


    <!-- ###################### -->
    <!-- # jbpm mapping files # -->
    <!-- ###################### -->

    <!-- hql queries and type defs -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/db/hibernate.queries.hbm.xml" />

    <!-- graph.action mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/action/MailAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/ProcessDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Node.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Transition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Action.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/SuperState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/ExceptionHandler.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/instantiation/Delegation.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.node mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/StartState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/EndState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/ProcessState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Decision.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Fork.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Join.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/MailNode.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/State.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/TaskNode.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- context.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/def/ContextDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/def/VariableAccess.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- taskmgmt.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/TaskMgmtDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/Swimlane.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/Task.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/TaskController.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- module.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/module/def/ModuleDefinition.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- bytes mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/bytes/ByteArray.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- file.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/file/def/FileDefinition.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- scheduler.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/scheduler/def/CreateTimerAction.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/scheduler/def/CancelTimerAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/Comment.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/ProcessInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/Token.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/RuntimeAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- module.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/module/exe/ModuleInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- context.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/ContextInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/TokenVariableMap.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/VariableInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/ByteArrayInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/DateInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/DoubleInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/HibernateLongInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/HibernateStringInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/LongInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/NullInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/StringInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- job mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/Job.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/Timer.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/ExecuteNodeJob.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/ExecuteActionJob.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- taskmgmt.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/TaskMgmtInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/TaskInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/PooledActor.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/SwimlaneInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- logging mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/ProcessLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/MessageLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/CompositeLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ActionLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/NodeLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessInstanceCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessInstanceEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessStateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/SignalLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TokenCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TokenEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TransitionLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableDeleteLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/ByteArrayUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/DateUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/DoubleUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/HibernateLongUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/HibernateStringUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/LongUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/StringUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskAssignLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneAssignLog.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---- edit ---

I have already tried the hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class to set to the JBoss version (org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup) it did not work...well it's not that suprising...I'll try now: org.hibernate.transaction.OC4JTransactionManagerLookup

I tried with CMT instead of JTA, but it didn't work also.

Comment: Maybe you diggin' too deep and something more obvious (like wrong classpath or missing jars) happens? I have working jbpm console deployed as .war in JBoss 4 connected to Oracle 10g and only differencies in my hibernate.cfg.xml are: another DS name and uncommented "hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" property.

Comment: I started with the simplest and most evident configurations but none of them worked... 
May be I'm missing something. Though 3 days spent with the problem should have been enough.

I admit that there's too many possibilities here, it's hard to tell anything "remotely".

Comment: AAAAnd in the end, you were right. I restarted the whole thing, and succeeded...:) It's fairly easy, I'll describe it in an answer.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have succeeded, thanx to Vanger's suggestion for restarting.
Maybe it's trivial but may help to someone, so I share it.

Previously I used an EAR and used the enterprise version of the WAR and probably that messed up the libraries.

A. In the WAR file I had change some files:

**web.xml:**

- setup the "user" security role, remove the "admin"

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

Uncomment these lines and change the lookup class to OC4JTransactionManager:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.OC4JTransactionManagerLookup</property>
```

B. The libraries have to be provided in the applib folder

C. During deployment you have to map the "user" role to the given Security Providers role.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this property?

```
<!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>-->
```

Comment: yes, I tried it (see edit), now i'll checkout org.hibernate.transaction.OC4JTransactionManagerLookup